# How do you properly update a web based system?

Tags: php, javascript

We have a small web based business system, used by 100ish users daily.

When doing updates we've run into some problems with users having to clear their cache before it will work properly.

This of course can be very frustrating for them.

So my question is. How do you avoid users having to clear their cache?

The system is written in PHP.

Comment: add a cachebuster: http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/ most likely to js and css files. php itself just serves unless the system itself it told to cache.

Comment: You could add a version query string to URLs of static resources. (That's what Stack Overflow does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the time webpages, images, styles and client side script is cached for in .htaccess using `Cache-Control`. Once the files on the users computer are older than the specified cache length, the browser will request new copies of expired data.

Some info here: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html

Comment: Actually, the module is called `ExpiresActive`, isn't it? That's how I do it on [my site](https://github.com/simevidas/ecmazing-site/blob/master/.htaccess).